# Applying styles to my Titanium UI

Tags: titanium, titanium-alloy

I'm just starting Appcelerator's Titanium Alloy.

How can I add styles to my **controller/index.js** here's the code:

```
var title = Titanium.UI.createLabel({
   title: "My Label",
   id: "myLabel"
});
```

I am trying this one on **styles/index.tss**

```
"#myLabel": {
 textAlign: "left",
 right: 15,
 color: '#000',
 font: { fontSize:20 },
 shadowColor: '#aaa',
 shadowOffset: {x:5, y:5},
 horizontalWrap: true
}
```

but unfortunately it's now working. Can anyone teach me on how to add styles to my Titanium UI

Answer (score 10):

Alloy style are applied automatically to views created through xml. If you want to keep that effect while you are creating objects inside controller you have to use [$.UI.create()](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/api/Alloy.Controller.UI-method-create) method instead of Titanium API. In your case your code will look like this:

```
var title = $.UI.create('Label', {
   title: "My Label",
   id: "myLabel"
});
```

For more read [Dynamic Styles guide](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/guide/Dynamic_Styles). It's not very well documented and some parts of it were unclear for me when I read it but it's good starting point to experiment with the code and learn Alloy behaviour.

Comment: That's why I'm scouring the interwebz now. The styles documentation is wordy and ambiguous.

Comment: That saved me hours of googling

Answer (score 2):

it seems that your problem is in the create statement, you should use a `text` property instead of `title`:

```
var title = Titanium.UI.createLabel({
   text: "My Label",
   id: "myLabel"
});
```

This way, you'll see the label, but the style it won't automatically be applied, so consider one of this options:

- If it's possible, create your label in the view:

  ```
  <Alloy>
      <View id="content" class="container">
          <Label id="myLabel" text="My Label"/>
      </View>
  </Alloy>
  ```

  That will work automatically applying the style `"#myLabel"` defined in your .tss file, and of course, you can always change the text value in code:

  ```
  $.myLabel.text = "New value";
  ```
- Other solution would be applying the style in code:

  ```
  var title = Ti.UI.createLabel({
      text: "My Label",
      id: "myLabel"
  });
  var style = $.createStyle({
      classes: ['myLabel']
      ,apiName: 'Label'});
  title.applyProperties(style);
  ```

  In this case, in your .tss file you need to replace `"#myLabel": {` for `".myLabel": {`

Comment: Your first answer is unrelated As you can see I declared a variable title for my label having a text property set to "My Label".

Second, I cannot just add my Label to the views because I am having a loop that will automatically creates a label.

Third, your last solution is is possible to just call the id of the label in the index.tss like this 
"#myLabel": {}

Comment: Hi Allen, so I think that the last solution would be perfect for you and I meant that you need to replace
     `"#myLabel": {
 textAlign: "left",
 right: 15,
 color: '#000',
 font: { fontSize:20 },
 shadowColor: '#aaa',
 shadowOffset: {x:5, y:5},
 horizontalWrap: true
}`

for

`".myLabel": {
 textAlign: "left",
 right: 15,
 color: '#000',
 font: { fontSize:20 },
 shadowColor: '#aaa',
 shadowOffset: {x:5, y:5},
 horizontalWrap: true
}`

Comment: Take a look on my answer. There is $.UI.create() method, not very well documented in Appcelerator documentations but fits exactly this use case.

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution is to add class like below,

```
$.addClass(yourView, "yourClassName");
```

add your class in `.tss` file.